# How to receive Discord.js interactions though POST requests at my endpoint

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a Discord Bot using [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org) and want to change it to receive interactions through POST requests instead of websockets, as the new option for Discord Apps:

> You can optionally configure an interactions endpoint to receive interactions via HTTP POSTs rather than over Gateway with a bot user.

Slash commands and interactions works as expected with websocks by using:

```js
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction) => {
  // receive and answer the interaction
})
```

The problem is, I can't find on the documentation how to explicitly receive interactions through http POST neither options to set the listening `PORT`.